# key error when trying to make a auth api "post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, flask, keyerror

im very new to react and coding in general im learning now to make api requests this is my react post request.

```
    handleSubmit(event) {
        axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/user", {
            user: {
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                streetAddress: this.state.streetAddress,
                city: this.state.city,
                state: this.state.state,
                zip: this.state.zip,
            },
        });
```

this is my flask api post method my error im getting is name = request.json['name']
KeyError: 'name'

```
@app.route ('/user', methods =['POST'])

def create_user():
    
    name = request.json['name']
    email = request.json['email']
    password = request.json['password']
    streetAddress = request.json['streetAddress']
    city = request.json['city']
    state = request.json['state']
    zip = request.json['zip']

    


    new_user = User(name , email, password,streetAddress,city,zip,state)

    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return user_schema.jsonify(new_user)
```

Comment: You need to first access the `user` key and then you can access `name`

Comment: access user on the python db or the react side? im not understanding how it should look

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route ('/user', methods =['POST'])

def create_user():
    data = request.json.get("user")
    name = data.get("name")
    email = data.get("email")
# and so on...
```

[explanation on .get()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp)

Comment: You can also send the data to the flask backend as a form by creating a form object in js, and then access the data like so: `name = request.form.get("name")` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: data = request.json().get('user')
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: remove the () in the json I accidentally added it, I update my answer respectively

Comment: Also, don't call your attr `zip`  there is a function with that name https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip and if my answer helped you can accept her